# C# Flyleaf Loading FFmpeg libraries ':FFmpeg' failed

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm trying to link ffmpeg libraries in EngineConfig

```
EngineConfig engineConfig = new EngineConfig();
engineConfig.FFmpegPath = @"C:\somepath";
```

Relative, absolute it doesn't matter.
Anyway it's always **"Loading FFmpeg libraries ':FFmpeg' failed"**

Summary for EngineConfig says

```
// Summary:
//     Required to register ffmpeg libraries. Make sure you provide x86 or x64 based
//     on your project.
//     :<path> for relative path from current folder or any below
//     <path> for absolute or relative path
```

I suggest that I am using improper libraries or something. I've got ones from official ffmpeg github as it is. Also I've tried FFmpeg.Autogen.dll, FFMpegCore.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it using the DDL I downloaded from [BtbN Build](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases).

I'm using version 5.1, which goes by the name "ffmpeg-n5.1-latest-win64-lgpl-shared-5.1.zip".

Answer (score 0):

Adding x86, x64 builds from configuration manager worked for me.

[image]